# Как к уже имеющийся дате добавить X дней?

Tags: php, datetime

В общем вот что написал, как это заставить работать?

```
    $strtotime = 30;
    $date = strtotime('2023.07.04');
    $validDate = date($date, strtotime("+$strtotime days"));
    echo $validDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$dateString = '2023.07.04';
$format = 'Y.m.d';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $dateString);
if ($date !== false) {
    $strtotime = 30;
    $date->modify("+$strtotime days");
    $validDate = $date->format($format);
    echo $validDate;
} else {
    echo "Ошибка при парсинге даты.";
}
```